# Grouping data in Python DataFrame

Tags: python

I have a dataframe as below:

```
        |  Year | Cause of Death  |Gender| Total Case  |
        | 2016  |    Killed       |   M  |      3      |
        | 2016  |    Suicide      |   M  |      5      |
        | 2016  |    Killed       |   F  |      7      |
        | 2017  |    Killed       |   F  |      12     |
        | 2017  |    Killed       |   M  |      2      |
        | 2017  |    Suicide      |   F  |      5      |
        | 2017  |    Suicide      |   M  |      6      |
```

From this dataframe, I want to create a new datafarame as below :

```
    |Year|Cause of Death|Total Case|
    |2016|   Killed     |    10    | 
    |    |   Suicide    |  5       |
    |2017|   Killed     |  14      |
    |    |   Suicide    |  11      |
```

Any simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Cause of Death'])['Total Case'].sum()

Year  Cause of Death
2016  Killed            10
      Suicide            5
2017  Killed            14
      Suicide           11
Name: Total Case, dtype: int64
```

From here, it's a matter of formatting:

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Cause of Death']).sum()

                     Total Case
Year Cause of Death            
2016 Killed                  10
     Suicide                  5
2017 Killed                  14
     Suicide                 11
```

Or

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Cause of Death']).sum().reset_index()

   Year Cause of Death  Total Case
0  2016         Killed          10
1  2016        Suicide           5
2  2017         Killed          14
3  2017        Suicide          11
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas DataFrame's come with a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function that acheieves this.  It looks like you don't care about the Gender column and instead just want to group by Year and Cause of Death.

```
g = df[['Year', 'Cause of Death', 'Total Cases']].groupby(['Year', 'Cause of Death'])
g.sum()

#                      Total Cases
# Year Cause of Death             
# 2016 Killed                   10
#      Suicide                   5
# 2017 Killed                   14
#      Suicide                  11
```

First line selects only the columns you are interested in, then calls `groupby` on the columns you want to group.  This returns a new object that has a function called `sum` that will sum the values in each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test_1.csv')
df
```

df is :

```
    Year    Cause of Death  Gender  Total Case
0   2016    Killed            M      3
1   2016    Suicide           M      5
2   2016    Killed            F      7
3   2017    Killed            F      12
4   2017    Killed            M      2
5   2017    Suicide           F      5
6   2017    Suicide           M      6
```

Then apply this:

```
new_df = df['Total Case'].groupby([df['Year'], df['Cause of Death']]).sum()
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
new_df
```

`new_df` will be:

```
    Year    Cause of Death  Total Case
0   2016    Killed          10
1   2016    Suicide         5
2   2017    Killed          14
3   2017    Suicide         11
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method "**groupby**" from Pandas.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Year', 'Cause of Death'])
```

Then to get the sum in total cases use this :

```
grouped.sum()
```

This will give your desired output

```
|Year|Cause of Death|Total Case|
|2016|   Killed     |    10    | 
|    |   Suicide    |  5       |
|2017|   Killed     |  14      |
|    |   Suicide    |  11      |
```